# Finding all polls that a specific user hasn't voted on yet

Tags: mysql

I have a website that displays poll after poll to a register user, and stores his vote in a table.
A simple structure of the database would be as follows (there are much more fields, but they don't contribute much to the question, so I removed them):

Polls(pollId)

Votes(pollId, userId, vote)

Now I want to run a MySql query to select all polls within the 'Polls' table, except for the polls that the current user had already voted on (which could be determined from the 'Votes' table)

Is it possible to make that using a MySql select statement alone, or will I have to select all polls first, and use some Php logic to filter out the ones already voted on by the user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Pools
 WHERE id NOT IN (
       SELECT poolId
         FROM Votes
        WHERE userId = 142
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select p.pollid from polls p where p.pollid not in (select v.pollid from votes v where userId = {USERID})
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate, that worked really well, but hsz was a bit faster, so I had to choose him :$

Comment: No problem, you've got your answer :)